# how can echo item in php foreach only at First item

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array $result and I want to echo $image for the first item only. My code this is:

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $item)
{
$image = $item->image;   
$id = $item->id;
$cat = $item->catid;
}
?>
```

i want echo $image in first item and don't echo it Second, or third, etc item

Comment: Use [`break`](http://php.net/break). But, if you only need to iterate once, then why use a loop at all?

Comment: `echo $result[0]['image'];`

Comment: You can use `list()` or `reset()` to get first element from an array.

Comment: @DigitalChris You can't be sure `$result` is a vector and not a map with string keys or unordered keys. `[0]` might not be there, or might not be first.

Comment: @CodeAngry true, saber didn't give enough detail to be sure. A `var_dump($result);` will tell us...

Comment: i want echo $image in first item and don't echo it Second, or third, etc item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$first = true;
foreach ($result as $item)
{

 $image = ($first) ? $item->image : '';   
 $id = $item->id;
 $cat = $item->catid;

 $first = false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$item = reset($array);
// do stuff with $item here
```

^ gets the first item of the array without removing it.

Or just `break` before the closing `}` in your code.

Comment: +1 can't understand some people trying to make their life harder when they can use single function to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

if you want display only first item, you can use array_shift

```
$item = array_shift($result);
$image = $item->image;   
$id = $item->id;
$cat = $item->catid;
```

Comment: This removes the item, not sure if the OP wants it!

Answer (score 1):

You can count your iteration and print only at first run

```
$i=o;
foreach ($result as $item)
{
    $image = $item->image;   
    $id = $item->id;
    $cat = $item->catid;
    if($i==0) 
    {
         echo $image;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('foo', 'baz', 'baz');
reset($arr);
$first = current($arr);
echo $first->image; // outputs 'foo'
```

Comment: i want echo $image in first item and don't echo it Second, or third, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $item)
{
  $image = $result[0]->image;   
  $id = $item->id;
  $cat = $item->catid;
}
?>
```